# Mongoose - how to use Schema parameters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a parameter

```
venue: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'venue'
}
```

and I want to extract the id that is passed into the schema in a findById function like :

```
Event. 
     Venue.findById(id, callback).
     populate('venue').
     exec(function (err,event) {
          if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

I know this isn't correct code - how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the value of the `Event` plus the value of the `Venue` behind the venue.id in `Event`?

```
Event.findOne({
  venue: id,
})
   .populate('venue')
   .exec()
   .then((ret) => {
     // ...
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     // ...
   });
```

Comment: I'm getting an id not defined error. If i understand you correctly yes, that's what I want. Basically the value of the venue to be produced by its id within event.

Comment: `venue: id,` Here you gotta provide the `id` you are looking for. It's a variable.

Comment: But i don't really want to specify a certain venue, I want to specify the venue when i make a PUT request if you know what i mean